# Show Images from third-part site using AWS CDN

Tags: image, amazon-web-services

We are currently using **AWS CDN** to fetch images uploaded. In Magento admin, if I upload any image, it goes to **CDN** and then it show me the `CDN` path in `<img src>`.

Now, we have a third party content site from where we need to show images using CDN.

In Magento, if the image is normally uploaded from admin it shows path something like:

`<img src="http://d56xhwfHe9rhq4.cloudfront.net/skin/frontend/package/theme/images/logo.gif" alt="" />`

For ex: `http://mysite.com/images/new-logo.gif` resides on my third party content site.

And if the image is coming from third party content site, it currently shows like

`<img src="http://thirdpart.com/media/images/new-logo.gif" alt="" />`

which should be like below with `CDN`

`<img src="http://d56xhwfHe9rhq4.cloudfront.net/media/images/new-logo.gif" alt="" />`

How can I make CDN work with both normal magento image upload from admin as well as showing third party images with complete path ?

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how AWS CDN is set-up have you tried http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5024/158

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by an extension, which you'll find in the web at [GitHub](https://github.com/onepica/imagecdn/tree/master/app/code/community/OnePica/ImageCdn/Model) (for free) or [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) (might cost something).

**First solution**: You need to rewrite some of the Core-Classes or -Methods, which is always dangerous (with each update of Magento and compatibility with other extensions).

**Second Solution**: You change the whole design, so that it uses a new class or method to deliver images or compose the path you need.

**Both cases** need additional options in the admin panel.

You also might want to use the search keywords "magento external images" in your favorite search engine, which gives you additional options and a hint like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293465/how-to-use-external-urls-for-product-images-in-magento

Answer (score 2):

I think you could stay out of the Magento code completely - Cloud-front distributions can point to multiple origin servers:

> Support for Multiple Origins - You can now reference multiple origins
>   (sources of content) from a single Cloud-front distribution. This means
>   that you could, for example, serve images from Amazon S3, dynamic
>   content from EC2, and other content from third-party sites, all from a
>   single domain name. Being able to serve your entire site from a single
>   domain will simplify implementation, allow the use of more relative
>   URLs within the application, and can even get you past some cross-site
>   scripting limitations.

from: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-dynamic-content/